# How do I put space between top of all elements inside a div?

Tags: html, css

Let's assume I have a HTML like this:

```
<div id='main'>
  <select name='foo'>
    <option>A</option>
    <option>B</option>
  </select>
  <br>
  <select name='baa'>
    <option>C</option>
    <option>D</option>
  </select>
  <br>
</div>
```

I'm looking for a CSS rule to make a space between top of these elements, like I had a `margin-top: 10px`; on every element in `main` div. How can I make this? Searching I found this solution:

```
border-collapse: separate;
border-spacing: 0 1em;
```

But it didn't work in the way I described.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like using a [css universal selector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Universal_selectors) will do the trick:

```css
#main *{ /* see the asterisk in the selector here, that's what you're after*/
  margin-top: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div id='main'>
  <select name='foo'>
    <option>A</option>
    <option>B</option>
  </select>
  <br>
  <select name='baa'>
    <option>C</option>
    <option>D</option>
  </select>
  <br>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Give your select a class, then add a margin to the class.

Like this:

```css
.center {
  text-align: center;
  color: red;
  margin-top: 10px
}
```

```html
<div id='main'>
  <select name='foo' class="center">
    <option>A</option>
    <option>B</option>
  </select>
  <br>
  <select name='baa' class="center">
    <option>C</option>
    <option>D</option>
  </select>
  <br>
</div>
```